# ImageDataBunch not loading in my files/labels

Tags: python, pytorch, fast-ai

I have a dataset of images stored on my local disk that I name as such:

```
path = '../input/resized/Resized Dataset.zip/Resized Data'
```

And I am calling an instance of an ImageDataBunch from the fastai.vision library using the following code:

```
data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path, train=".", ds_tfms=get_transforms(),size=224, valid_pct=0.2)
```

but for some reason I am getting an error

```
File "../src/script.py", line 17, in <module>
    data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path, train=".", ds_tfms=get_transforms(),size=20, valid_pct=0.2)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/vision/data.py", line 110, in from_folder
    src = src.label_from_folder(classes=classes)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/data_block.py", line 463, in _inner
    self.train = ft(*args, from_item_lists=True, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/data_block.py", line 292, in label_from_folder
    label_cls=label_cls, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/data_block.py", line 287, in label_from_func
    return self._label_from_list([func(o) for o in self.items], label_cls=label_cls, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/data_block.py", line 262, in _label_from_list
    label_cls = self.get_label_cls(labels, label_cls=label_cls, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/data_block.py", line 251, in get_label_cls
    it = index_row(labels,0)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/core.py", line 250, in index_row
3.5s
3
    return a[idxs]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I have used multiple different datasets and have the same problem